# How does Rails know which environment to use?

Tags: production-environment, ruby-on-rails-5.1

How does Rails (5.1) know which environment it is supposed to run in?  All I've been able to find is that in nginx.conf a passenger_env variable seems to be set.

I seem to remember reading about a RAILS_ENV variable but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that passenger_app_env is ALL that is required to let know which Rails environment to load.

I found the answer here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

It's not immediately apparent but if you work through the Initialization Process you will find where the environment variable is set.

Comment: (I've removed a secondary question from this answer, since it might cause the answer to fall into the Review Queue and be deleted as NAA (Not An Answer)).